# May I Binding to Array's item? (indexer's item)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

```
string[] fruits = new string[] { "apple", "banana", "orange", "etc" };

public string[] Fruits
{
    get { return fruits; }
    set { fruits = value; }
} 

public ApplicationPresenter(MainPage mainpage0, Adatok adatok0)
{
    startPage = mainpage0;
    startPage.DataContext = this;
    uc_adatok = adatok0;
    uc_adatok.DataContext = this;
    Binding binding = new Binding(/*at here, May I set the property's item?
        I imagine this for example "Fruits[0]" but it doesn't work*/);
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(uc_adatok.Mennyiseg, TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
}
```

thx the answers;

Answer (score 1):

It should work just fine. Have your tried to simplify your scenario? It is possible that you have the DataContexts confused between your user controls etc.

A simple page with the following control

And the following code behind, works as expected.

```
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  DataContext = this;
  Binding binding = new Binding("Fruits[2]");      
  BindingOperations.SetBinding(txtTest, TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
}
```